# How to find current NFS mount parameters

Tags: nfs, sles

We've been having some problems with the parameters for some NFS mounts on a server, and we've changed the `/etc/fstab` settings, and rebooted the server (a SUSE Linux 11 server).

However I've just been told not all the settings changes have taken effect...

I was running `mount` to check the current mount parameters (and seeing the new settings), but my colleague is running `nfsstat -m` and being given the old settings on some of the mounts!

Which of these commands is likely to be more accurate?

Comment: Please provide the output of both commands (`mount` and `nfsstat -m`), the relevant lines from your `/etc/fstab` file, and specify exactly what you're expecting to see and not see.  Censor information (IPs, hostnames, etc) as needed.

Comment: The value changed is the timeo parameter, which shows as timeo=50 in mount, and timeo=15 in nfsstat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/proc/mounts`, you will find all actual mounts used by the kernel including effective mount options.

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
```

Comment: Thank you, that agrees with the results from `nfsstat -m` (a few of the mounts are still on the old timeout)

Comment: If the results from `cat /proc/self/mounts` differs from `mount`, it means your */etc/mtab* is not a symlink to the former. In modern distros it's commonly linked this way. Check [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69286) on Unix&Linux StackExchange and [mount manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).